# Selenium. No internet connection

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

need some help. I've been working with selenium for a long time, I'm not a beginner.

Faced with a very strange problem, the solution to which I can not find.

For some reason (which I can't figure out), Selenium loses its Internet connection. That is, I just open the console, create a new Selenium instance, call the driver, but nothing happens at all, after 10-15 seconds of loading any Internet site, I get the standard error window - no Internet connection.

I tried changing the version of the webdrivers, to no avail.
I tried to kill all webdriver related processes, to no avail.
I don't use any proxies or any additional settings, just a single instance of the webdriver in the code.

Now the most important thing, the **ONLY** thing that helps me, is rebooting my system (MAC).
Does anyone have any thoughts on this? I'm at a loss for ideas. Where else can I try to find the problem? Can I see the internal webdriver console, maybe I can find errors there?

UDP:
@kaliiiiiiiii

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

The point is that there is no "special" example. This is a normal instance of the driver class.

After rebooting it works properly. Something is going on with some process that is blocking internet access for the driver, causing me to have to reboot the system (my guess), but this process is not the webdriver.

Comment: Doe other applications have internet-acesss ?

Comment: @kaliiiiiiiii yep, ofc :)

Comment: PLease provide a sample code. Also, Does it have acess after rebooting? What's the problem after rebooting then?

Comment: @kaliiiiiiiii Added to UPD

Comment: After reboot, at which point does it stop working?

Comment: @kaliiiiiiiii That is part of the mystery. Frankly, it happens unexpectedly. For the most part, however, it happens after a long driver session. That is, if the driver window has been open for example an hour and has not been used.